# In State design pattern Why the main class need to know about all the states at the beginning?

Tags: design-patterns

I was reading a book about design patterns and the code was written as :
example:

```
 class Fan{
   private IState State1;
   private IState State2;
  .
  .
  .
   public IState getState1(){
     return State1;
   }

   public IState getState2(){
     return State2;
   }
```

and then in each state gets the next state from the Fan class:

```
public class State1 implements IState{
 .
 .
 .
  public void execute(){
  .
  .
  .
   this.Fan.setState(this.Fan.getState2());
}
}
```

Now my question is why not just saying  this.Fan.setState(new State2()); instead of    this.Fan.setState(this.Fan.getState2()); ? I searched on the internet many people suggested that's the correct way of doing it but I couldn't find the reason for that! Can someone tell me why is advantage of it ?

Comment: I don't think that It is a good idea to let your main workflow object know about all the states, it should not have to. It should have only the knowledge of the current state, and each state once called, at the end of its behavior, it design the next current state.

Comment: That was what I was thinking of, but 3 famous books (e.g: head first ) did it that way which has raised that question for me.

Comment: I read it, it is for illustration but it does not put all oop best practices toguether, you should try to encapsulate as much as you can, this is a rule of thumb for a well designed oop code.